# Посчитать, сколько пользователей приобретали товар как минимум в двух разных странах

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, pandas

кто в сей час решил уделить чуточку внимания к данному посту. попрошу вашего внимания в решении своей небольшой задачи, с которой не могу справиться. вернее, у меня нет как таковой идеи для решения этой задачи. прошу вашей поддержки, спасибо вам заранее <3

по сути самой задачи как в названии:

- высчитать количество пользователей с одинаковым ID, которые приобретали товар как минимум в двух различных странах. (своебразные путешественники)

выглядит примерно так:

- ID у пользователя 581581, совершил пять покупок в стране United Kingdom. - его в счет не берем
- ID у пользователя 581582, совершил три покупки в трех странах - United Kingdom, France и Italy. - берем в счет как единицу
- ID у пользователя 581583, совершил шесть покупок в двух странах - United Kingdom и France. - аналогично берем в счет как единицу, т.к. пользователь совершил покупки как минимум в двух разных странах.

датафрейм выглядит примерно так, но в нем гораздо больше значений:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 536365 | United Kingdom |
| 536365 | United Kingdom |
| 536365 | United Kingdom |
| 536366 | United Kingdom |
| 536366 | United Kingdom |
| 536367 | France |
| 536367 | France |
| 536367 | France |
| 536368 | United Kingdom |
| 536368 | France |
| 536368 | Italy |
| 536369 | United Kingdom |
| 536369 | France |
| 536369 | United Kingdom |
| 536370 | Italy |
| 536370 | Italy |
| ... | ... |
| 541906 | France |
| 541906 | Italy |
| 541907 | Russia |
| 541907 | Russia |
| 541907 | Russia |
| 541908 | United Kingdom |
| 541908 | United Kingdom |
| 541908 | Latvia |
| 541909 | United States |
| 541910 | Russia |
| 541910 | Latvia |
| 541910 | United Kingdom |

желаемый результат - вывод, одно целое число (примерное):

> 210

так как у меня нет ни малейшей идеи, мой примерный код лишь выводит таблицу:

```
strangers = df[['InvoiceNo', 'Country']]
strangers.groupby('InvoiceNo')['Country']
strangers.nunique()
```

которое выводит

```
InvoiceNo    18533
Country         37
dtype: int64
```

но это не совсем то, что мне нужно, все таки оно отображает количество уникальных значений,
поэтому прошу вашей помощи
спасибо заранее :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала оставьте только тех пользователей, которые удовлетворяют условию. После этого посчитайте число оставшихся уникальных пользователей:

```
res = df.groupby("ID").filter(lambda x: x["Country"].nunique() > 1)["ID"].nunique()
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще одно похожее решение:

```
res = (df.groupby("ID")['Country'].nunique() > 1).sum()
```